# cannot able to import file from a certain module

Tags: react-native

I cannot able to import certain file from a certain module, I have attached snapshot code, tree structure, error

[Error](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12d-msG_Ga3UWgtPxlOmsoA-uxZWucGOx)

[Tree structure](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1R4Y_TUzht3y8KvHvfSD8cTaV3j093qSq)

[Code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1g-ptjejr4DCS01jHRzdqsKSCK6jqNJ9r)

Comment: the two files are in the same level ...connect way >>  `import Home from './Home';`
the  dot stands for >> current location

Comment: that helpful @HendEl-Sahli